# jQuery Only serialize 'visible' elements

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to produce a serialized list of elements inside the container `#dd_menu_edit_items` - however, I only want to serialize the current 'visible' items inside the container. `#dd_menu_edit_items:visible` doesn't appear to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$('#dd_menu_edit_items:visible').sortable('serialize')
```

Markup is:

```
<div id="dd_menu_edit_items" class="cust_menu_options">
   <? foreach($menus as $m_menu) { ?>
      <a id="ed_dd_<?=$m_menu['id']?>" class="ddGroup_<?=$m_menu['menu_id']?>"><div class="menu_icons"></div><?=$m_menu['dd_title']?></a>
   <? } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, use classes instead.

Comment: It serializes the contents of the containing div. It works as it is.. it just gathers ALL contents, rather then only the visible contents. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post your markup? You are filtering the container, one element.

Comment: I modified the main entry to include the markup. Some elements in the container get dynamically hidden on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

You are filtering the container, if you want to select visible `a` elements, you can code:

```
$('#dd_menu_edit_items a:visible').sortable('serialize');
```

Or if you want to select all visible children:

```
$('#dd_menu_edit_items').children().filter(':visible').sortable('serialize');
```

Comment: Of course - thank you. However, now when I alert that out I'm not seeing the serialized output - I get "[object Object]" ?

Comment: @xtiaan You are welcome, `alert` doesn't show object's properties/methods, you can use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Sorry, I am just a little confused. Previously when i'd alert the output, I'd see the expected ed_dd[]=7&ed_dd[]=8&ed_dd[]=1&ed_dd[]=2 etc. Now with your filter code solution above, instead of seeing this serialized output in the console, I see the raw code with all the <a> and <div> tags etc in the output - not the ed_dd[]=7&ed_dd[]=8 as before?

Comment: @xtiaan Are you sure you are using serialize method after filtering?

Comment: Yes - I used it exactly as: `$('#dd_menu_edit_items').children().filter(':visible').sortable('serialize');`